# Is there a slice method that only applies to the end of a string?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, slice

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  Is there a slice method that only removes a string if it occurs at the end of a string?  If my string ends with a string from anotehr array, I want to remove it from the original string, but I'm discovering this doesn't work ...

```
2.4.0 :001 > TOKENS = ["a", "b", "c"]
 => ["a", "b", "c"]
2.4.0 :002 > str = "33333a"
 => "33333a"
2.4.0 :003 > if str.ends_with?(*TOKENS)
2.4.0 :004?>   str.slice!(TOKENS)
2.4.0 :005?>   end
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into Integer
    from (irb):4:in `slice!'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

In the above example, I would expect the original string to be changed to just "33333".  How do I remove a string from another string but only if it occurs at the end of that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-sub) with a regular expression.

```
TOKENS = ["a", "b", "cat"]

r = /
    (?:                   # begin a non-capture group
      #{TOKENS.join('|')} # match one of the tokens
    )                     # end non-capture group
    \z                    # match end of string
    /x                    # free-spacing regex definition mode

#=> /
#   (?:                   # begin a non-capture group
#     a|b|cat             # match one of the tokens
#   )                     # end non-capture group
#   \z                    # match end of string
#   /x

"I want some grub".sub(r, '')
  #=> "I want some gru"
"I want some chips".sub(r, '')
  #=> "I want some chips"
"My feline is a tomcat".sub(r, '')
  #=> "My feline is a tom"
```

Here is another way that uses the method [String#end_with?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F).

```
str = "I want some grub"
str[0, str.size - (TOKENS.find { |t| str.end_with?(t) } || '').size]
  #=> "I want some gru"
```

*Addendum*

@Schwern makes a good point in his comment. Suppose

```
TOKENS = ["a", "b", "cat", "pig?"]
```

then

```
r #=> /(?:a|b|cat|pig?)\z/x
```

making `'g'` optional. Here are two ways we might fix the regex (the first suggested by Schwern):

```
r = /(?:#{TOKENS.map { |s| Regexp.escape(s) }.join('|')})\z/   
  #=> /(?:a|b|cat|pig\?)\z/      

r = /#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}\z/
  #=> /(?-mix:a|b|cat|pig\?)\z/
```

Both escape the question mark, so we could use either, right? There is a difference, however, in that `union` adds the modes `i` (case indifference), `m` (multiline) and `x` (free-spacing), which we may or may not want. If whatever modes we want should apply to the entire regex it would be better to use the `Regexp#escape` option and add any desired modes manually (e.g, `/.../i`). See [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html) for the docs for `escape` and `union`.

Comment: Watch out when joining strings like that into a regex. A string like `Hello?` will be interpreted as the regex `/hello?/` which means `hell` maybe followed by an `o` and will strip the `hell` from `Go to hell`. You probably want to run each token through [`Regexp.escape`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) like `TOKENS.map { |str| Regexp.escape(str) }.join('|')`, or make the user aware that `TOKENS` are regexes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be looking for [`chomp!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp-21).

```
tokens = ["a", "b", "c"]
str = "33333a"
tokens.each {|t| str.chomp!(t)}
```

Though, to be honest, I'd do it the way Cary suggests, using `sub` with a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only characters in `tokens`, `include?` and `chop!` could be nice.

```
tokens = ["a", "b", "c"]
str = "3333a"
str.chop! if tokens.include?(str[-1])
```